# What steps to consider for make my own "old cottage window"

Tags: wood, windows, glass

Assume I would have a wooden frame of an old typical window and enough small parts of glass.

Which steps do I need to consider in the process of making an "old cottage window" out of this? (Is it even possible?)

I add a photo of the result I would prefer

[image: Window divided with wooden borders into smaller parts filles with glass]

Comment: [How to Make Stained Glass (with Pictures) - wikiHow](https://www.wikihow.com/Make-Stained-Glass)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you for this. But I do not want stained glass, instead the borders between glass should be wooden ones. I assume then it is more easy to replace broken parts. But for cutting glass the wiki-how will be useful!

Comment: Your first photo show lead pieces between the glass ...

Comment: [TheWoodHaven2 • View topic - Making glazing bars](https://thewoodhaven2.co.uk/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=1743)

Comment: Do you want to do the "original" way with small pieces of glass arranged (how are your glass cutting skills), or the "quick" way where the piece of glass is full size and you stick the wood lathe on in the pattern wanted.

Comment: It is possible.  Three things/knowledge you need first, are glass cutting skill(probably want twice as many pieces than you need for mistakes),  decent woodworking skill(more than just nailing two 2x4s together), and how to take measurements.  I might be able to do it, but making it look nice first try is iffy.

Comment: @DavidPostill I am sorry I mislead you first. The first image was stained glass, because I did not find a better one. Now I found the thing I really want.

Comment: @SolarMike My intention was to re-use small pieces of glass (ie broken parts of bigger windows)

Comment: How to recreate historical windows from scratch using found or hand-made parts is not in scope for this DIY Forum.   I suggest you look at [Woodworking](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/) or at any of countless woodworking chat forums some of which specialize in recreating historical architectural features.  I belong to a FB group [Historic Home Renovations](https://www.facebook.com/groups/739389589552353) and there is a guy there who does *nothing but* renovate and recreate old windows.  He makes and collects special tools to do it.  It's amazing.  He has his own page too.

Comment: Despite huge respect for the question and the desire to learn, I vote to close for the reasons noted in my previous comment.

Comment: @jay613 I did not want to do this window from scratch. I wanted to know, if it is possible to do so with some glass and the wooden frame of an old window. But if this is out of scope I am sorry I did not notice before.

Comment: No need to apologize ... it's delightful to see people getting into this.   Just there are better places.  If you mean that you HAVE a window like this and just want to replace the glass that will be relatively easy, but expect that some parts of the frame will be damaged or rotten, and that as noted here already, new glass won't look like historical glass.  If you can get pieces of historical glass (with the uneven wavy look like in your pic) it will look better.  Mounting the glass in the frame is easy.  Repairing the frame is hard.

Answer (score 2):

These windows date from before the invention of float glass, when panes were indvidually spun by glass blowers, and large sheets of glass were unotainable.

For windows with wood between panes of glass you're going to need carpentry experience like tenon joints. and wood shaping with routers or edge planes.

Cutting and fitting the glass is the sort of thing you can learn in a few hours by watching videos.

Those who want this effect cheaper glue sticks of PVC to both sides of a plain window. You can spot a fake because it looks too good.

The real deal has putty holding the panes in and putty is never perfectly flat, also the putty is painted over onto the glass, and also the panes of glass will be at slightly different angles causing distant reflections to be shattered.

Comment: Windows are **very advanced finish carpentry** which is why most people buy them from specialists, so a lot of hands-on learning will be required to make a decent one, indeed. So, start practicing...

Comment: Have PVC windows with wooden grid fitted over.  Even just making replacement pieces for the wooden grid was not fun.  About 1/2 x 3/4 with notches every 6 inches.

Comment: Would you maybe have a picture, how such a joint looks like before the glass and putty is added?

Comment: @Allerleirauh **wooden window sash joinery** in the search engine of your choice. Or **muntin joinery**

Comment: @Ecnerwal Thank you! Sometimes for non natives simple the right words are missing

Comment: @Allerleirauh even many native speakers don't know those specialized terms for window parts. An associate hates painting them, so I have terminology beat into me. ;^)

Comment: [Here](https://www.facebook.com/100063613060371/posts/pfbid0LXBnsqPQemhYxQRee8qXAUQZjpmdLt6qyDnZpN8z45D7Lyn3y6BwGstLQJjbTxWdl/) is a post from someone who renovates historical windows for a living.  He occasionally offers apprenticeships to young people interested in keeping the craft alive.  He has special tools for each different part of a window.